# Finding security name from yahoo finance using matlab

Tags: matlab, yahoo-finance

If I type:

```
 txt=urlread('http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv', 'get',{'s', 'AAPL', 'f', 'sl1d1t1c1ohgv', '', '.csv'} )
```

in matlab, I get the output:

```
"AAPL",430.195,"7/16/2013","4:00pm",+2.755,426.43,430.71,424.17,7616916
```

However I want to get the name of the security, in addition to the ticker symbol. I believe `'n'` is the way to signify this but I haven't been able to get it to work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just adding `'n'` to the `'f'` parameter's value?:

```
txt=urlread('http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv',...
            'get',{'s', 'AAPL', 'f', 'nsl1d1t1c1ohgv', 'e', '.csv'} )
```

which returns

```
txt = 

    "Apple Inc.","AAPL",430.195,"7/16/2013","4:00pm",+2.755,426.43,430.71,424.17,7624941
```

I found [this page](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvQuotesDownload) helpful. The list of all property names and their descriptions is [here](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/enumQuoteProperty).

Comment: Woah I didn't know I could do that. Thanks so much.