# MATLAB script to look up stock symbol -- where do I start?

Tags: matlab

I need to look up stock symbols for 7500+ companies. I'd like MATLAB to do it for me.

How would I write a script that looks up a ticker symbol given a search string? e.g. that automatically queries a site like this: http://www.nasdaq.com/quotes/symbol-lookup.aspx

The ability to do fuzzy search or wildcards is a plus.

Any insight appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a particular programming question? You might see [the Matlab question just beneath yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686427/finding-security-name-from-yahoo-finance-using-matlab) for a hint.

Comment: Good point, @horchler. I do believe the OP was trying to learn more about all of this web API and REST and JSON stuff, though, and was looking for a place to start.

Comment: "How to write MATLAB script to XYZ"  Well, normal people open MATLAB and its Editor Window and start typing code.  Trying it first in the Command Window and copying from there to the script is a really nice option.  On the other hand, you can use any text editor as long as you save the script as plain text with a `.m` extension and place it on MATLAB's path.  If you're feeling really daring, use another programming language to open a text file and write script commands into it!  Oh wait, your question wasn't really about how to write a script?

Comment: Thanks a lot to @bbill for setting me on the right path! :) Just needed a push in the right direction with the JSON stuff. I've added my own more complete answer below.   

horchler the answer you pointed to requires the stock symbol as an *input*, I needed it as an output.   

BenVoigt Thanks for your useless contribution. Must be nice to have that much time to waste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to bbill for setting me on the right track. I've decided to answer my own question because it represents a complete answer and will hopefully be more helpful to anyone else with this question. Additionally, this implementation does not require a JSON package. This function is more complete, and uses the Yahoo Finance API as suggested by bbill. I've also included a second answer that uses MarketWatch.com but is less complete (see below).

```
% Get a stock ticker symbol from Yahoo Finance.
%
% get_stocksymbol('searchstring','default1') takes two arguments:
%   'searchstring' is the company name to be looked up.
%   'default1' is y/n -- set to 'y' to default to the first result if
%       the search return multiple results.
%
% stocksymbol = get_stocksymbol(searchstring,default1) returns a string
% with the result of the stock symbol lookup.
%
% [stocksymbol,choices] = get_stocksymbol(searchstring,default1) returns
% the optional cell array of company name and symbol choices.
%
% The function looks up the search string using the Yahoo Finance API (but
% without requiring the use of a JSON library) and returns all possible
% stock symbols provided by Yahoo. If more than one symbol is returned,
% the user is given the option to select the most appropriate.
%
% Trevor Zink 2013

function [stocksymbol,choices] = get_stocksymbol(searchstring,default1)

fsearchstring=strrep(searchstring,' ','%20');
url = strcat('http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=',fsearchstring,'&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback');

try
jsonread = urlread(url);
catch errmsg
    stocksymbol = 'NA';
    fprintf('No company named %s exists in the database \n',searchstring)
    return
end
% search the JSON output for the desired term (in this case, ticker symbol)

% handle the case where either data not available or no symbol
no_data = strfind(jsonread, '"Result":[]}})');
if ~isempty(no_data),
    fprintf(1,'No symbol for %s.\n',searchstring);
    stocksymbol = 'NA';
    return;
end

% extract the symbol(s)
% find a term in the JSON output that preceeds the stock symbol(s) (in this
% case, "symbol"):
occ = strfind(jsonread, '"symbol"');
clear choices
for i=1:length(occ)
% the next four lines find characters at the beginning and the end of
% the actual stock symbol itself
sym_lt = strfind(jsonread(occ(i):end),':"');
sym_rt = strfind(jsonread(occ(i):end),'",');
nam_lt = strfind(jsonread(occ(i):end),'"nam');
nam_rt = strfind(jsonread(occ(i):end),'","ex');
jsonshort = jsonread(occ(i):end);
% then just grab the section of the JSON output inbetween the delimiters we
% established above
choices(i,1)= {i};
choices(i,2) = cellstr(jsonshort(sym_lt+2:sym_rt-1));
choices(i,3) = cellstr(jsonshort(nam_lt+9:nam_rt-1));
end

% choose from multiple options, if available
clear choice
if or(size(choices,1)==1,default1=='y')
    stocksymbol=choices{1,2};
else
    for i=1:size(choices,1)
        % this part is a bit over the top, but formats the choices in a
        % pretty table for the user to choose from
        if size(choices{i,2},1)>6
        fprintf('%i)\t\t%s\t\t%s \n',i,choices{i,2},choices{i,3})
        else
            if size(choices{i,2},1)>3 && length(choices{i,2})<=6
        fprintf('%i)\t\t%s\t\t\t%s \n',i,choices{i,2},choices{i,3})
            else
        fprintf('%i)\t\t%s\t\t\t\t%s \n',i,choices{i,2},choices{i,3})
            end
        end
    end
    fprintf('Company: %s\n',searchstring)
    choice = input('Choose an option number (default 1; choose 0 for ''NA''):');
    if isempty(choice)
        choice=1;
    end
    % account for incorrect entries
    if choice > length(choices)
        valid_response = 0;
        while ~valid_response
            choice = input('Invalid selection. Choose an option number: ');
            if choice <= length(choices)
                valid_response = 1;
            end
        end
    end
        if choice==0
            stocksymbol='NA';
        else
            stocksymbol=choices{choice,2};
        end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick-and-dirty way similar to ones I've used before.

Yahoo! has an API: http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=facebook&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback. (Try the link) You just need to replace the query parameter with each company - a simple for loop should do it.

In Matlab, call it with

```
result = urlread(url);
```

If you looked at the API, it looks like it will come back with `"YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback("JSON")"` wrapping the JSON. Since urlread() just returns a string, replace those characters so you have valid JSON.

And finally use a JSON library like [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20565-json-parser) and read the result:

```
stock = parse_json(result.ResultSet.Result(1).symbol);
```

For "fuzzy" lookup, you might just want to check past the first result.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html#btgyt2u Has more information on the urlread function if you want to put in the parameters programmatically rather than using a hacky replace.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly less complete version (no ability to select from competing options), but it uses output from MarketWatch.com. This is based largely on an example from [Luminous Logic blog](http://luminouslogic.com/how-to-import-stock-statistics-into-matlab.htm).

```
% Retrieve stock ticker symbols from MarketWatch.com
% Trevor Zink 2013
% Code based largely on example from
% http://www.luminouslogic.com/matlab_stock_scripts/get_trailing_pe.m


% Initialize Workspace
% function trailing_pe = get_symbol(searchstring)

fprintf(1,'Retrieving symbol for %s... \n', searchstring);
url_name = strcat('http://www.marketwatch.com/tools/quotes/lookup.asp?siteID=mktw&Lookup=',searchstring,'&Country=all&Type=All');
url     = java.net.URL(url_name);        % Construct a URL object
is      = openStream(url);              % Open a connection to the URL
isr     = java.io.InputStreamReader(is);
br      = java.io.BufferedReader(isr);

% Cycle through the source code until we find searchstring...
while 1
    line_buff = char(readLine(br));
    ptr       = strfind(line_buff, strcat('title="',searchstring));

    % ...And break when we find it
    if ~isempty(ptr),break; end

    % Handle the case where either data not available or no symbol
    no_data   = strfind(line_buff, 'There were no matches found');
    if ~isempty(no_data), 
        fprintf(1,'MarketWatch.com does not have a symbol for %s.\n',searchstring);
        symbol = NaN;
        return; 
    end
end

% Just to make it easier, strip off all the preceeding stuff we don't want
line_buff   = line_buff(ptr:end);

% Extract the symbol
ptr_gt      = strfind(line_buff,'>');
ptr_lt      = strfind(line_buff,'<');
symbol = line_buff(ptr_gt(1)+1:ptr_lt(1)-1);
if printsymbol=='y'
    if isempty(symbol)
        fprintf(1,'N/A\n');
    else
        fprintf(1,'%s\n',symbol);
    end
end
```